Failing to deploy smart contract through ganache gui
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

async function main() {
  try {
    const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545");
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
      "0x3fff57a423422c9af7026a90b58be81e66bd80e7587edd7ec61060f6daaed287",
      provider
    );

    const abi = fs.readFileSync(
      "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi",
      "utf8"
    );
    const binary = fs.readFileSync(
      "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin",
      "utf8"
    );

    const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
    console.log("Deploying, please hang on...");

    const contract = await contractFactory.deploy({
      gasLimit: 6721975,
      gasPrice: 20000000000,
    });

    console.log("Deployment Transaction:", contract.deployTransaction);

    console.log("Waiting for the contract to be mined...");
    await contract.deployTransaction.wait(1); // Wait for 1 block confirmation
    console.log("Contract deployed successfully!");

    // Call the `retrieve` function on the deployed contract
    console.log("Calling retrieve method...");
    const favNumber = await contract.retrieve();
    console.log("Favorite number:", favNumber.toString());
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during deployment or function call:", error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

main();

Now when i try to deploy ``node deploy.js` , here is the terminal error that pop ups
and my progress been halted right there,
rror during deployment or function call: Error: could not coalesce error (error={ "code": -32000, "data": { "hash": "0x71df1abf7ca0c92341bcbe285a19c83102635b35d9964bb5a1ba5da1b3456ddb", "message": "invalid opcode", "programCounter": 23, "reason": null, "result": "0x71df1abf7ca0c92341bcbe285a19c83102635b35d9964bb5a1ba5da1b3456ddb" }, "message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode", "name": "RuntimeError", "stack": "RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\n    at EIP1559FeeMarketTransaction.fillFromResult (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:12745)\n    at Miner.<anonymous> (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:36703)

code=UNKNOWN_ERROR, version=6.13.4)
    at makeError (/Users/wasimchoudhary/ethersjs blockchain/ether-ssstorage/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:129:21)
    at JsonRpcProvider.getRpcError (/Users/wasimchoudhary/ethersjs blockchain/ether-ssstorage/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/provider-jsonrpc.js:730:41)
    at /Users/wasimchoudhary/ethersjs blockchain/ether-ssstorage/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/provider-jsonrpc.js:302:45
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'UNKNOWN_ERROR',
  error: {
    message: 'VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode',
    stack: 'RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\n' +
      '    at EIP1559FeeMarketTransaction.fillFromResult (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:12745)\n' +
      '    at Miner.<anonymous> (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:36703)\n' +
      '    at async Miner.<anonymous> (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:35116)\n' +
      '    at async Miner.mine (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:39680)\n' +
      '    at async Blockchain.mine (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:60063)\n' +
      '    at async Promise.all (index 0)\n' +
      '    at async TransactionPool.emit (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/node_modules/emittery/index.js:303:3)',
    code: -32000,
    name: 'RuntimeError',
    data: {
      hash: '0x71df1abf7ca0c92341bcbe285a19c83102635b35d9964bb5a1ba5da1b3456ddb',
      programCounter: 23,
      result: '0x71df1abf7ca0c92341bcbe285a19c83102635b35d9964bb5a1ba5da1b3456ddb',
      reason: null,
      message: 'invalid opcode'
    }
  },
  payload: {
    method: 'eth_sendRawTransaction',
    params: [

 id: 9,
    jsonrpc: '2.0'
  },
  shortMessage: 'could not coalesce error'

removed the hashes and binary form the terminal and here is the long summed up error
Wanted to deploy through ganache gui local environment tried every npm installs etc and dependencies and hence i am finding my lost

Why are you using that? I see your deployment script is really barebones, if you are a beginer I wouldn't recommend that. Try somthing like Apeworx, Hardhat or Foundry.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
